# Custom TabBarController containing scrollable Tabs and has more than 5 tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, custom-controls, scrollable

I am developing an app where I have more than 5 tabs at the bottom and don't want to use the UITabBarController which limits unto 5 tabs and more Tab, so I am looking for the alternative to the custom TabBar which can give the scrolling functionality to choose any tab. I came across this [custom tab bar](https://github.com/jain-mohit/CustomTabBar) which is good but I am looking for option which can have similar look to the UITabBarController tabs with label at the bottom and image. Please suggest some options guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need implement your custom tabbar - with 2 views:

1-st view - content view. You will add current selected controller to    it as subview.
2-nd view - tabbar view. You will have collection    view    here. Each cell will be your button. When cell is selected    you add    view controller for this cell to content view.

**UPDATE**:

Take a look on this example: https://github.com/antrix1989/CustomTabBar/tree/master/CustomTabBar

Comment: sorry for delayed response, can you provide some code or example link